# Using Intern for nodejs only app

Tags: node.js, intern

I was trying running intern-client for nodejs server-side application. The terminal error I receive is

> "node plugin failed to load because environment is not Node.js"

I tried adding

```
hasCache: {
        "host-node": 1, // Ensure we "force" the loader into Node.js mode
        "dom": 0 // Ensure that none of the code assumes we have a DOM
    },
```

configuration to my intern.js config file but no success.

Can anyone please suggest a way to configure intern for node-only apps using dojo.

Thanks

Comment: have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22572008/how-to-mock-a-node-js-module-loaded-with-dojo-node

Comment: This worked - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329026/how-to-run-intern-to-test-a-dojo-application-running-with-node-js